# Django background task runner on server?

Tags: python, django, parallel-processing

I'm trying to run a background task runner on the Django web server. I'm not that familiar with Django but I've done this with asp.net before. So essentially I have the html and JS send a post, which will be a file, usually a huge file, then Django will send back a hash for which to check the status of the file upload. The website will then have a processing bar that tells the user what percent is uploaded or if it has crashed. Is there a way to do this in Django? In C# there's things called delegates for this, where you can just check the status of the job, but the web server still receives requests, cause I want to site to keep pinging the server to get the status.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/#file-uploads) in more detail how to handle file uploads in Django. A common way you might handle an uploaded file is

```
def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('some/file/name.txt', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Looping over **UploadedFile.chunks()** instead of using **read()** ensures that large files don’t overwhelm your system’s memory.

There are a few other methods and attributes available on UploadedFile objects; see [UploadedFile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile) for a complete reference.

Depending on how big it is you might need to change [FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-max-memory-size).

Comment: Thanks this is useful, but my question is more about running this in the background and using REST to check the status of it. Cause some files I'm uploading can be gigabytes in size. So I upload the file then on the front end a status report is show and it can keep pinging the backend to see the status and update the UI

Comment: Got it. Not sure if there's such functionality that allows you to upload a file in the FE and then be moving around through other pages while it uploads. Best scenario I can think of is to use AJAX to upload the file to the server and create a JavaScript script to display the progress. [Hint](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/22/django-multiple-file-upload-using-ajax.html).